# Terminé mi programa en c#, ¿cómo hago el ejecutable?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

A parte de crear el ejecutable, ¿cómo hago para la base de datos? Puesto que la conexión a la base se ha hecho con mi ordenador, ¿cómo hago para que cualquier usuario pueda usar las tablas, y colocar sus datos?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español René. Te van a cerrar la pregunta como "no está claro lo que se pregunta". Aunque sí está bastante claro lo que preguntas ese motivo de cierre en realidad significa que a tu pregunta le faltan detalles. Pero puedes fácilmente solucionarlo editando tu pregunta, poniendo el código de tu programa (no todo, solo la parte en que se conecta a la base de datos). Y el error que te da cuando ejecutas el programa con otro usuario. Si haces eso verás como pronto se reabre tu pregunta y recibes buenas respuestas.

Comment: La información que proporcionas no es suficiente, pero creo que esto te puede servir:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo hago para la base de datos? Puesto que la conexión a la base se
>   ha hecho con mi ordenador, ¿cómo hago para que cualquier usuario pueda
>   usar las tablas, y colocar sus datos?

La conexión a la base de datos debe de ser configurable desde la aplicación. No puedes '*harcodear*' la conexion en la aplicacion en el codigo asi por que si.

> ¿Cómo hago el ejecutable?

Los ejecutables de la aplicacion estan en la carpeta `bin` del codigo fuente de la aplicacion. Pero si lo que quieres es generar un instalador, te recomiendo [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php#features), es gratis y [muy facil de utilizar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wP9HcD4oPDw&t=253s).

Answer (score 1):

la conexion con la base de datos ya la tiene la aplicación que hiciste, en caso de que la aplicacion sea para comercio debes darle la base de datos a la que la aplicacion se conecta para que funcione.

y el ejecutable que hiciste esta en la carpeta bin/debug ó bin/Release, alli tambien se encuentran librerias que creaste para que la aplicacion funcione.